# Script block as the value of dictionary?

Tags: powershell, closures, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to implement the following powershell script?

The purpose is to call the script blocks later to get the html controls.

```
$sites = @{
    site1= @{ 
        url = "......."; 
        inputUserID = { $doc.getElementsByID("username"]) }; #Some code to get the html input control
        inputPassword = { $doc.getElementsByName("passowrd"]) }; #Some code to get the html input control
    };
    .....
}

$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate($sites[$site]["url"])
$ie.visible = $true
while ($ie.busy) { start-sleep -milliseconds 1000; }

... #Get the input controls and fill the values
```

---

**The question has been updated. Is it clear enough? It shouldn't be so hard to understand.**

Comment: This really needs to be clarified -- I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan I have data structure `$sites` to store all the site related information. Instead of save the input element ID/Name... of some controls (`inputUserID`, `inputPassword`, etc), I want to store the code to get these controls because each sites may have different ways to get these controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get a closure from a scriptblock in PowerShell is to do this:

```
{  #code here  }.GetNewClosure()
```

It's hard to tell from the code above if this will help any, but it's what you asked for.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  The original question asked how to get a closure from a scriptblock.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each site's information.  I'm not sure how you're using the DOM selectors with the IE COM object, so I guessed that part of the code:

```
$sites = @{
    site1= @{ 
        url = "......."; 
        inputUserID = ( 'doc.getElementsByID("username")' ); #Some code to get the html input control
        inputPassword = ( 'doc.getElementsByName("passowrd")' ); #Some code to get the html input control
    };
    .....
}

$sites.Keys | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $siteInfo = $sites[$_]
        $ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
        $ie.navigate($siteInfo.url)
        $ie.visible = $true
        while ($ie.busy) { start-sleep -milliseconds 1000; }
        ... #Get the input controls and fill the values
        $usernameElement = $ie.someFunction( $siteInfo.inputUserID )
        $passwordElement = $ie.someFunction( $siteInfo.inputPassword )
    }
```

Comment: What's the `$ie.someFunction`?

Comment: It's whatever function you're using to get access to the page's DOM.